# common event for all elements on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events

I want to fire a common event whenever a value of any element in form changes. On the basis of  values  of form elements i want implement code.

i am writing below code but onchange event is not working on formid.

```
$("#formid").change(function () {
    //code 
}); 

or this

$("#formid").bind("change", function () {
    //code 
});
```

How to fire  event on form  whenever there is any change in element's value ?

Answer (score 3):

> How to fire event on form whenever there is any change in element's value ?

Just do as it looks like you've done. Bind the `change` event to the `form` element.

```
$("form").change(function() {
   // Some descendant changed.
});
```

So long as you're not interfering with the propagation of the events, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind change event for all necessary form controls

```
$('input, select, textarea', $('#formid')).change(function()
{
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: I added your syntax, specified the type and it worked. However, why it didn't work without specifying type is still a mystery for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all elements of your document or form and set their onChange event to your handling function. Like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < yourelements.length; i++)
yourelements[i].onchange = change;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).toArray().each(function(index, element){
    $(element).change(function(){.....});
```

});

put this in document.ready...