# Entire form on change

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events, onchange

How can I use `change` or a similar event for all `form` elements? I don't want to use `change` for each field separately.

Comment: why not? In the HTML event you could call the same function everytime, so it's a matter of copy-pasting probably no more then 20 characters and writing 1 function.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546076/common-event-for-all-elements-on-form) help?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can use the `change` event on the `form` element:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('change', function() {
    alert('Hi!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. After doing some tests - I'll just add that the 'change' event here is just perfect for this, because for text inputs it doesn't fire for every keydown, but, just like we would expect -  on blur if there was a change. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/54dftpL6/ - so it seems to be **the** solution for "save form automatically on any change" task, which I've just completed in time much shorter than I expected :)

Comment: Thumbs up for answering your own question 6 years later.

Comment: A form control that is not a descendant of its form element (possible with the `form` attribute) will not bubble the event up to the form element. To accomodate such cases we could instead add the event listener to `document.body` and check `event.target.form` matches the intended form.

Comment: As of 2022-06 a `textarea` inside your form will not trigger the form's change event :(

Comment: If you have a reset button in the form you need to subscriber to "reset" event as well.

Answer (score 43):

If you are using jQuery, you can use the `change` event on the form element, because in jQuery the event bubbles up.

```
$('#formId').change(function(){...});
```

If you are using plain javascript, the change event does not bubble (at least not cross browser).  So you would have to attach the event handler to each input element separately:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
   inputs[i].onchange = changeHandler;
}
```

(of course, you would have to do a similar thing to all selects and textareas)

Comment: Now it seems that all major browsers support `form onchange`.

Comment: @Mori - can you elaborate on your comment please, what support is there for form onchange now?

Comment: @Tony Merryfield: Now `formElement.addEventListener('change', doSomething);` works in all major browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - do you know what the minimum IE version is that supports it? I can't find any decent information for the searches I've done - probably too generic in my search terms... :)

Comment: @TonyMerryfield: IE9

Comment: That's great - thanks. I never did manage to find any information about this but have been using it on a project and works fine for the browsers we support :)

Comment: @Mori Why not make a real answer from your comment?