# Using Javascript, how can you determine whether any control on an ASP.Net page has had its value changed?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, client-side-scripting

I have a web page containing a FormView. If user clicks the edit button it changes to Edit mode. I then have a Javascript `onbeforeunload` function which traps the user with a confirmation dialog if he or she attempts to navigate to a different page in the web site. It says 'You are in Edit Mode. Leave this page?'. However, I only want that confirmation to display if the user has made at least a single change to any of the FormView's controls. There are a lot of controls in the FormView. It seems silly to prompt the user even if he or she changed nothing.

So, in Javascript, is there a way to determine if any control has been changed, or must I implement client-side event handlers for each and every TextBox, CheckBox, RadioButton, and DropDownList on the page?

Answer (score 0):

[Dirty Forms](http://mal.co.nz/code/jquery-dirty-forms/), a Jquery-based project may help.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate? Check out the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760847/entire-form-onchange). In jQuery you can listen to the form's change event, as changes to individual fields will bubble to it.