# HTMLFormElement change event support

Tags: javascript, html, forms, event-listener

All major browsers seems to support `change` event on the `HTMLFormElement`.
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846602/1627401)
It is triggered whenever any child Form Control Element's value is changed.
This seems to be better approach than adding Event Listeners on all control elements.
However, I'm not able to find any reference to this in any of the documentations
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

My question is, is it valid/safe to use this in production code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add it to a higher element.

The event is emitted from the individual form controls elements, but you are simply listening at a higher level.

See: https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html and the section labeled `Event bubbling`. `change` events will bubble up and so you can monitor them as you describe.