# Validate each input before activating the next button

Tags: javascript

I have some inputs and a next button. At the moment I validated that the button is deactivated. If I fill in the name field, the button is activated.

```js
var b = document.getElementById('button');
var input = document.getElementById("inputtext");

input.addEventListener("input", displayButton); 

function displayButton() {
    if (input.value === "") {
        b.disabled = true;
    } else {
        b.disabled = false;
    }
}

displayButton();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter name">
<input type="text" id="inputtext2" placeholder="Enter last_name">
<input type="text" id="inputtext3" placeholder="Enter country">
<button id="button">Next</button>
```

If I only want to verify that the first and last name are filled and not the city field, how would it be?
And also if I click on the disabled button insert a text that says "First fill all the fields".

Comment: if you wrap all your inputs in a `form` element, you can observe the `change` event directly on the form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760847/entire-form-onchange

Comment: Add variables for all of the inputs; only enabled the button if all three elements have a value? Disabled buttons don't receive the click event; you'd need to wrap the button and listen for delegated events.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an event listener to all the `<input>`'s, then on input, check if [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) inputs don't have a value, use that to enable/disable the button. (Using [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) so we ignore whitespaces)

Regarding the *"First fill all the fields"* message, a `disabled` button can't be clicked.

You could add some logic to the `validate` function below that will set some message in another component.

```js
var b = document.getElementById('button');
var inputs = [ ...document.querySelectorAll("input") ];

const validate = (e) => {
    b.disabled = inputs.some(ii => !ii.value.trim().length)
}

inputs.forEach(i => i.addEventListener("input", validate));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter name">
<input type="text" id="inputtext2" placeholder="Enter last_name">
<input type="text" id="inputtext3" placeholder="Enter country">
<button id="button" disabled>Next</button>
```

---

Edit: Based on [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77009762/validate-each-input-before-activating-the-next-button/77009815#comment135758532_77009815), the same idea but with a `querySelcetorAll` that just targets 2 out of 3 fields. (I've renamed the field `id`'s to something more descriptive.

```js
var b = document.getElementById('button');
var inputs = [ ...document.querySelectorAll("#input_name, #input_last_name") ];

const validate = (e) => {
    b.disabled = inputs.some(ii => !ii.value.trim().length)
}

inputs.forEach(i => i.addEventListener("input", validate));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input_name" placeholder="Enter name">
<input type="text" id="input_last_name" placeholder="Enter last_name">
<input type="text" id="input_country" placeholder="Enter country">
<button id="button" disabled>Next</button>
```

Comment: thanks, I understand that this verifies that all the "inputs" in my template right?

If I only want to verify that the first and last name are filled and not the city field, how would it be?

Comment: I'm using `document.querySelectorAll("input")` to find all the `<input>`'s. You could change it to something like `document.querySelectorAll("#inputtext, #inputtext2")` to only check some inputs. Change the selector to your likings.

Comment: @ele0603 please edit your question accordingly, where you say `when I fill in the 3 entries and not just the first one`

Comment: I've added a (collapsed) snippet showing the querySelectorAll with just 2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Mark inputs as required

```html
<form id="someId">
  <input type="text" id="inputtext" required placeholder="Enter name" />
  <input type="text" id="inputtext2" required placeholder="Enter last_name" />
  <input type="text" id="inputtext3" placeholder="Enter country" />
  <input type="submit" id="button" value="Next" />
</form>
```

Use built-in form validation

```js
const form = document.getElementById("someId")
form.addEventListener("submit", ev => {
  ev.preventDefault()
  // Notifies user as well
  const isValid = form.reportValidity()
  if (!isValid) return
  // process data from inputs
})
```